# Vue: Change Class In V-For-Loop On ONE Link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I make ONE link in the FOR-Loop `active`?

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="channel in $store.state.forum.channels" v-bind:key="channel.key">
    <a v-bind:class="{ active: toggle }" v-on:click="selectChannel({ key: channel.key })">{{ channel.title }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or:

How can I access an iteration in the for loop from outside the loop?

Comment: Use an expression that identifies the active link by its associated data like `:class="{active: channel.key === activeKey}"`

Comment: thank you very much. this helps. :D